# Slick Slider offset

Tags: slider, slick.js

Is there a way to make my slider behave like center mode, but make it say the 2nd slide?

For example where there are 4 slides, it will normally mark the 1st one as active.

**But i need the 2nd to be the active one.**

By default its the far left one when more than one is showing.

```
$('.slideshow').slick({
        centerPadding: '60px',
        focusOnSelect: true,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1024,
                settings: {
                    arrows: false,
                    centerPadding: '40px',
                    slidesToShow: 3
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 992,
                settings: {
                    arrows: false,
                    centerPadding: '30px',
                    slidesToShow: 2
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {
                    arrows: true,
                    centerPadding: '30px',
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the adjacent sibling selector to style the slide besides the first one `div.slick-current + div {background-color: #f00;}`.